# Writing for loop in a better way in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for optimized solution for my problem, I do have a solution but it is time taking process.

There are 2 Dataframes:

```
Df1: 
Hid     MST     Date      Percent  year_1_back     Avg_Percent 
1        1    01-01-2018     .90    01-01-2017     0
```

DF1 has in total 19,900 records

```
DF2:
Hid     MST     Date      Percent  
1        1    01-01-2017     .90   
1        1    02-01-2017     .91
```

I have the data in DF2 till today

So, now I want to update the column Avg_Percent in DF1, by taking 1 year data from DF2 with the average of Percent.

Existing logic:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(DF1)){
  #row = 1
  hid <- DF1[row,]$hid
  mst <- DF1[row,]$mst
  startdate <- DF1[row,]$year_1_back
  enddate <- DF1[row,]$Date
  test1 <- DF2[which(DF2$Date>= startdate & DF2$Date<= enddate & DF2$MarketSegmentType == mst & DF2$hid== hid),]
  AVG <- mean(test1$Percet)
  DF1[row,]$Avg_Percent <- AVG
}
```

This gives me the result but it is taking very long time to execute. I think dplyr would be useful but don't know how to use that function.

I'm looking for some code which is faster than the existing one.

Comment: generally, the `map` functions from `purrr` package are a good option to replace a `for`-loop

Comment: Do you have any example, which I can use as an example?

Comment: Note that `purrr` family of functions (like `*apply` family) just hides the for loop, just to be clear.

Comment: yeah true, I used apply in one of my use case earlier. Thank you @RLave

Comment: Feel free to post the solution as a self-answer.

Comment: but that wouldn't be optimized right, I'm looking for some better solution. Lets see if no one replies then I will write the answer. Thank you so much @RLave

Comment: Sorry I misread your first comment, try to add more details about your data, a reproducible example should help. Try with `dput` on a small sample.

Comment: Without a bigger sample of test data it's difficult to help, but this could be done quickly and easily in `dplyr` using the following steps: first use `DF1` to assign a `time_period` variable to every observation in `DF2`. Then, on `DF2`, use `group_by(hid, mst, time_period)` and `summarise` with function = mean to get the desired result.

Comment: this sounds like an easy job for a `non-equi join` using `data.table`... the performance of these joins is very very good.. add some sample data, and I'll have a go at it.

Answer (score 2):

We can do a JOIN using `sqldf` based on `df1.Date >= df2.Date AND df1.year_1_back <= df2.Date`, then group by and summarising.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)
sqldf::sqldf("SELECT a.Hid AS a_Hid, a.MST As a_MST, a.Date, a.year_1_back, b.Hid, b.MST, b.Percent, b.Date AS DF2DATE
FROM df1 a
JOIN df2 b on a.Hid = b.Hid AND a.MST = b.MST AND
a.Date >= b.Date AND a.year_1_back <= b.Date") %>% 
       as_tibble() %>% group_by(a_Hid, a_MST, Date, year_1_back) %>%
       summarise(Percent=mean(Percent, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   a_Hid, a_MST, Date [?]
     a_Hid a_MST Date       year_1_back Percent
     <int> <int> <date>     <date>        <dbl>
  1     1     1 2018-01-01 2017-01-01    0.905
```

Comment: Suggest doing it all in sql (rather than a mix of packages) like this: `library(sqldf); sqldf("SELECT a.Hid, a.MST, a.Date, a.year_1_back, 
  avg(b.Percent) AS Percent
FROM DF1 a
LEFT JOIN DF2 b on a.Hid = b.Hid AND 
                   a.MST = b.MST AND
                   b.Date BETWEEN a.year_1_back AND a.Date
GROUP BY 1, 2")`